# How to create citation, co-citation and bibliographic coupling networks in python?

Tags: python, charts, networkx, igraph, network-analysis

I am working currently in a small passion project to understand citation network.
After some research, I came across three types of major citation analyses:
direct citation, co-citation and bibliographic coupling.

I was able to produce direct citation network in python. But creating co-citation and bibliographic coupling has been little trickier, though I understand their differences.

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns:
article column and a second column of list of articles that cites the main article column.

Can someone provide me a code based example to create these kinds of networks?
Appreciate the help!
Thank you

Code example I used for direct citation:

```
data = {
    'cited_articles': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'citing_articles': [['B', 'C'], ['C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['B']]
}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(df['cited_articles'])

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    cited_article = row['cited_articles']
    citations = row['citing_articles']
    for citation in citations:
        G.add_edge(citation, cited_article)
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and not clear enough. Please read [ask].

Comment: Could you give an example of your direct quotation network code?

Comment: @fabelx it's 'citation' not 'quotation'. See code example above.